# Get Factor Levels of other Vector (and lump non-existent ones)

Tags: r

I got two factors

```
foo_1 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "Other"))
foo_2 <- factor(c("a", "b", "x"))
```

I want to recode `foo_2` so that

1. the levels are the same as in `foo_1`
2. levels that do not exist in `levels(foo_2)` (`"x"`) are recoded to the `"Other"`-level.

So, something like

```
bar(foo_2, foo_1)

[1] a     b     Other
Levels: a b c Other
```

---

**Background**

I am building `randomForest()`s and there can be levels in the prediction data that do not exist in the development data and the prediction is not possible, which is very annoying. (`foo_1` is the vector from the development data and `foo_2` is the one from the prediction data.) I would make a bet that others must have had the same problem before and that the answer should be out there, but I couldn't find it.

I would love a solution using the `forcats` package, but other ways are also highly welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like below

```
> replace(u <- foo_1[match(levels(foo_2),levels(foo_1))],is.na(u),"Other")
[1] a     b     Other
Levels: a b c Other
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be :

```
foo_3 <- factor(foo_2, levels = levels(foo_1))
foo_3[is.na(foo_3)] <- 'Other'
foo_3
#[1] a     b     Other
#Levels: a b c Other
```

---

In `forcats` I could find `fct_other` which does exactly that but it does not keep the missing levels. (`c`) so you have to add it later.

```
library(forcats)
foo_3 <- fct_other(foo_2, levels(foo_1))
foo_3 <- fct_expand(foo_3, levels(foo_1))
```

Comment: Thanks. The `forcats` solution is not correct, though.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Ronaks answer and making it a little more elegant using the `magrittr` pipe (`%>%`):

```
library (forcats)

foo_2 %>% fct_expand(levels(foo_1)) %>% fct_other(levels(foo_1))

[1] a     b     Other
Levels: a b c Other
```